# Roku Spotx Integration

Tags: roku, advertisement-server

I am building an OTT application, and now i want to integrate the Spotx (https://www.spotx.tv/) add server to my Roku aplication.

I have done some research in Roku about advertising and came across the **RAF-Roku advertising Framework** (https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Roku+Advertising+Framework) in documentation. But not sure how i can integrate third party add server with the Roku application.

Can i do it without using RAF or is it necessary that i should use RAF to do advertising in Roku.

Any help would be much appreciated!! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Roku Ad framework allows developers to continue using their preferred ad server (e.g. Freewheel, DFP).

You can use the VAST tag in Roku Ad Framework after configuring the ads on spotx.tv

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use RAF with SpotX ads. 
Moreover, Roku *requires* you to use RAF for ads, for consistent implementation and experience between apps. So do that.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use RAF but, Roku highly recommends it and will only allow you not to use it on a case by case basis.

Answer (score 0):

You can play your Spotx URL through Roku Ad Framework.
Spotx URL will look like this -https://search.spotxchange.com/vast/2.0/000000?VPI[]=ROKU&VPI[]=MP4&app[bundle]=com.appName.star.56555&player_height=1080&player_width=1920&device[devicetype]=7&device[make]=Roku&device[model]=Roku&app[name]=AppName][1]

Now pass this URL to RAF-

```
 m.adIface = Roku_Ads()
 m.adIface.setAdExit(false)
 m.adIface.setAdUrl("spotxURL")
```